# Хочу помощника написать, нужны советы. Python

Tags: python

Всем привет, хочу написать своего помощника, посоветуйте какие-то библиотеки(пока-что текстового, потом уже на голосовой переведу), Как вот считали например текст, и посмотреть есть ли в нем это слово? (Например переменная your_text = input(), как в ней проверить есть ли слово "Помощь"?) Ну и еще какие-то библиотеки, кому не сложно

Comment: Советую при создании помощника использовать библиотеку pyautogui, она позволит вам управлять мишкой и клавиатурой как угодно, например: с помощью pyautogui можно нажать win + r после ввести туда cmd и выполнить какую либо команду

Comment: Я знаю, я ее и использую, но я еще хочу чтобы он еще что-то кроме управления делал, типа "Мне скучно" и отвечать что-то, я там допишу

Comment: `как в ней проверить есть ли слово "Помощь"?` - `if "Помощь" in your_text: ...`.

Comment: Распознавание команд когда-то  делал за счет нейросетей, работало все прекрасно.  Правда у меня была цель именно в экспериментах с нейросетью так что другие варианты не рассматривались.

Answer (score 1):

1. библиотека fuzzywuzzy для сравнение введённого слова с данными примерами.
2. понадобятся такие библиотеки как PyAudio и pyttsx3 для голосового озвучивания.
3. а уже для считывания голоса понадобятся speech_recognition для распознавания голоса.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую!

Comment: Если надо могу скинуть ссылку со статьей о  fuzzywuzzy